# How to have Keycloak login page in iframe?

Tags: iframe, keycloak, hapi.js, search-guard

There is a web server running locally, and I want to have Keycloak (on another domain) login page inside the iframe. I tried the following setting in the Keycloak Real Settings > Security Defenses > Headers > Content-Security-Policy

```
frame-src 'self' http://127.0.0.1 http://192.168.1.140 http://localhost *.home-life.hub http://trex-macbook.home-life.hub localhost; frame-ancestors 'self'; object-src 'none';
```

Basically, I put my local IP addresses and host names as sources to `frame-src`.

The login page is not shown and I get this error in the browser console

```
Refused to display 'http://keycloak.example.com:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=es-openid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fkibana.example.com%3A5601%2Fauth%2Fopenid%2Flogin&state=3RV-_nbW-RvmB8EfUwgkJq&scope=profile%20email%20openid' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

My custom headers are present
[image]

My server and UI (server rendered) code:

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');

const init = async () => {
  // Run server on all interfaces
  const server = Hapi.server({
    port: 3000,
  });

  await server.start();

  // server.ext('onPreResponse', (req, h) => {
  //   req.response.header('Content-Security-Policy', "default-src 'self' *.example.com");
  //   console.log('req.response.headers', req.response.headers);
  //   return h.continue;
  // });

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/home',
    handler: () => {
      return `<html>
                <head>
                  <title>searchguard kibana openid keycloak</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                  <p>
                    <iframe src="https://kibana.example.com:5601" width="800" height="600"></iframe>
                  </p>
                </body>
              </html>`;
    },
  });

  server.route({
    method: '*',
    path: '/{path*}',
    handler: (req, h) => {
      return h.redirect('/home');
    },
  });

  console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};

process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

init();
```

The iframe should show a page on kibana.example.com in the end. The Keycloak is used as an identity provider for the kibana.example.com.

Comment: How did you use Key Cloak login inside iframe?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to change:

```
frame-ancestors 'self';
```

to

```
frame-ancestors 'self' http://127.0.0.1 http://192.168.1.140 http://localhost *.home-life.hub http://trex-macbook.home-life.hub localhost;
```

Generally, tweak frame-ancestors CSP configuration.

Comment: I've got running on, let's say, https://auth.mysite.com. 
I set the CSP to `frame-src 'self' https://auth.mysite.com; frame-ancestors 'self' https://auth.mysite.com; object-src 'none';` and still get this error. I can even see in the header under the Network tab of the client application: `Content-Security-Policy: frame-src 'self' https://auth.mysite.co.za; frame-ancestors 'self' https://auth.mysite.co.za; object-src 'none';` Was CSP all you had to change?

Comment: Content-security-Policy can be found under Realm Settings -> Security Defenses